# Angular unit test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am extends bootstrap modal like this:

```
.directive("modal", [function(){
    var controller = function($scope, $attrs, $element, $uibModal){
        var defaultOptions = {
            title: "Modal title",
            content: "Modal body",
            controller: "DefaultModalController",
            templateUrl: "js/dev/shared/directives/templates/default-modal-template.html"
        };

        $element.on($scope.event, function(){
            var userOptions = {
                title: $attrs.title,
                content: $attrs.content,
                templateUrl: $attrs.templateUrl,
                controller: $attrs.controller
            };
            options = angular.extend({},defaultOptions, userOptions || {});

            $uibModal.open({
                templateUrl: options.templateUrl,
                controller: options.controller,
                resolve: {
                    options: function () {
                        return options
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    };

    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            event: "@"
        },
        controller: ["$scope", "$attrs", "$element", "$uibModal", controller]
    }
}])
.controller("DefaultModalController", ["$scope", "$modalInstance", "options",
        function($scope, $modalInstance, options){
    $scope.modalOptions = options;

    $scope.close = function(){
        $modalInstance.close();
    }
}]);
```

and my test looks like this:

descr

```
ibe("ModalDirective", ()=>{
    var element,
        compile,
        scope,
        controller;
    beforeEach(module("app.directive"));
    beforeEach(inject((_$compile_, _$rootScope_, _$controller_)=>{
        compile = _$compile_;
        controller = _$controller_;
        scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
        element = angular.element("<button modal>test</button>")
    }));

    it("should create default modal window", ()=>{

        element = compile(element)(scope);
        console.error(element.html());

        expect(true).toBeTruthy();
    })
});
```

but when `compile(element)(scope)` is executing I've got this error:

TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'd.indexOf')
        at a (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.min.js:179)

What should I do to fix it?

**[ EDIT ]**

I fixed this, the problem was in creating directive.
In directive definition I have:

```
scope: {
    event: "@"
}
```

and my template was `<button modal>test</button>` when I changed it to `<button modal event='click'>test</button>` problem was solved.

Comment: Try using the unminified version of Angular for a more meaningful error message. By the looks of it, it seems that it's trying to use the function `indexOf()` for an Array object, however the object is not an Array

Comment: Thanks for hint, after I change `angular.min.js` to `angular.js` error changed to this: `TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'type.indexOf')` but there is no `type` expression in my cod